# Is a 10/100 switch sufficient for Voice?

Tags: switching, power-over-ethernet, voice

Seems like a rudimentary question, but I'd like to use an "old" HP Procurve 2610 10/100 switch to provide POE connectivity to a new batch of ~25 deskphones.  It appears as though a generic bandwidth requirement is about 100 kbps for each phone/line.  Thus, it seems like I should only require ~ 2.5 mbps for all my deskphones to make calls concurrently.

Is there any reason to think about using a gigabit POE switch for voice connectivity or should I expect the following solution to work well for such a small office?

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

If only phones are connected to the switch, you should be fine.  If you also have PCs connected in tandem (switch<->phone<->PC), then you need to worry about QoS capabilities on the switch.

Comment: I have dedicated CAT5e cables to each office/desk already that are separate from the cable used for data.

Answer (score 1):

A 10/100 switch should suffice from a bandwidth perspective. But I would recommend considering a Gigabit switch for it's full duplex capabilities if your existing 10/100 (FastEthernet) switch is only capable of half duplex.

Comment: Switches are full duplex. It is hubs which must be half duplex.